# Turn 3 input nor gate into 4 input nor gate in d flip flop

Tags: logic-gates

I am making a negative edge triggered d-flip flop using the schematic attached, I have already put in the reset (attached) but the reset needs me to have a 4 input nor gate, which isn't provided in the program I'm using. What I am asking is how I would turn this 3 input nor gate into a 4 input nor gate. I was thinking something like what I drew on the side of the diagram, but I don't know if it would work.

[image]

Comment: Rotate your picture dude.

Comment: ill try but its a scan

Comment: the image size is over 2MB when i try

Comment: No it wasn't. You need to try harder.

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't work:

\$(A+B + (C+D)')' \ne (A+B+C+D)'\$.

Try this using three 3 input NOR gates:

\$((A+B+C)'' + D+0)' = (A+B+C+D)'\$
[image]

Comment: so how would I go about doing it then?

Comment: @liaiwen How about a 2-input OR?

Comment: could you draw that please?

Comment: @liaiwen updated with the drawing

Comment: isnt the 2nd nor gate just an inverter?

Comment: Yes. That trick allows making a higher input gate using lower input gates:  `((A+B+C)'' + (D+E+F)'' + .... )' = (A+B+C+D+E+F+...)'`